# SQL time difference between two rows in a partition window

Tags: sql, partitioning, amazon-athena

I have a table of analytics events and I'm trying to calculate the time difference between two rows, i.e. the time it takes a user between trying to start and actually starting.

My data looks like this:

| # | session | type | recordedAt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | D4E77C | feedbackProvided | 2021-08-17T09:13:00.768+03:00 |
| 2 | D4E77C | feedbackProvided | 2021-08-17T12:06:03.301+03:00 |
| 3 | D4E77C | feedbackProvided | 2021-08-17T14:28:15.083+03:00 |
| 4 | D4E77C | feedbackProvided | 2021-08-17T14:28:17.12+03:00 |
| 5 | D4E77C | buttonClicked | 2021-08-17T14:28:18.383+03:00 |
| 6 | D4E77C | measurementStarted | 2021-08-17T14:28:22.437+03:00 |
| 7 | D4E77C | buttonClicked | 2021-08-17T14:28:23.572+03:00 |
| 8 | D4E77C | measurementCancelled | 2021-08-17T14:28:23.573+03:00 |

These are just the rows for a given session, assume there are lots of sessions.

I'm trying to calculate the difference in `recordedAt` between the first feedbackProvided and the first measurementStarted. However, I only want the first feedbackProvided to be considered if it's within, say, 3 minutes of the measurementStarted. So in this case, we'd look at the difference between 1 and 6 but the time is >3 minutes. 2 and 6, time is >3 minutes. 3 and 6, time is ~7 seconds.

I've been looking at some partitioning for the first time and I'm close but I can't figure out the 3 minute maximum time difference.

Am I on the right lines here?

```
WITH firstFeedbackProvided AS (
  SELECT 
    session, type, recordedAt,
    ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by session order by recordedAt) rn
  FROM events
  WHERE type='feedbackProvided'
),
firstMeasurementStarted AS (
  SELECT 
    session, type, recordedAt,
    ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by session order by recordedAt) rn
  FROM events
  WHERE type='measurementStarted'
)
SELECT 
  *,
  date_diff('millisecond', t1.recordedAt, t2.recordedAt) as diff
FROM firstFeedbackProvided as t1
JOIN firstMeasurementStarted as t2 ON t1.session = t2.session
WHERE t1.rn = 1
AND t2.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are overcomplicating the problem.  Do the following:

1. Calculate when the first measurement occurred for each session.
2. Filter the rows to only include feedback events before this within your timeframe.
3. Aggregate

In SQL, this looks like:

```
select session,
       first_measurementStarted - min(recordedat) 
from (select e.*,
             min(case when type = 'measurementStarted' then recordedat end) over (partition by session) as first_measurementStarted
      from events e 
     ) e
where recordedat > first_measurementStarted - interval '3' minute and
     type = 'feedbackProvided'
group by session, first_measurementStarted;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest next interpretation of gaps-and-islands problem - filter out everything which is not `measurementStarted` or `feedbackProvided`, create groups based on previous row being `measurementStarted`, find maximum time in group (which should be one for `measurementStarted`) and use it to filter out `feedbackProvided` records from group.

Data:

```sql
WITH dataset AS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM 
    (
      VALUES 
('D4E77C',  'feedbackProvided',  from_iso8601_timestamp('2021-08-17T09:13:00.768+03:00')),
('D4E77C',  'feedbackProvided', from_iso8601_timestamp('2021-08-17T12:06:03.301+03:00')),
('D4E77C',  'feedbackProvided', from_iso8601_timestamp('2021-08-17T14:28:15.083+03:00')),
('D4E77C',  'feedbackProvided', from_iso8601_timestamp('2021-08-17T14:28:17.12+03:00')),
('D4E77C',  'buttonClicked',    from_iso8601_timestamp('2021-08-17T14:28:18.383+03:00')),
('D4E77C',  'measurementStarted',   from_iso8601_timestamp('2021-08-17T14:28:22.437+03:00')),
('D4E77C',  'buttonClicked',    from_iso8601_timestamp('2021-08-17T14:28:23.572+03:00')),      
('D4E77C',  'measurementCancelled', from_iso8601_timestamp('2021-08-17T14:28:23.573+03:00')),
      
('D4E77C1', 'feedbackProvided',  from_iso8601_timestamp('2021-08-17T09:13:00.768+03:00')),
('D4E77C1', 'feedbackProvided', from_iso8601_timestamp('2021-08-17T12:06:03.301+03:00')),
('D4E77C1', 'feedbackProvided', from_iso8601_timestamp('2021-08-17T14:28:15.083+03:00')),
('D4E77C1', 'feedbackProvided', from_iso8601_timestamp('2021-08-17T14:28:17.12+03:00')),
('D4E77C1', 'buttonClicked',    from_iso8601_timestamp('2021-08-17T14:28:18.383+03:00')),
('D4E77C1', 'measurementStarted',   from_iso8601_timestamp('2021-08-17T14:28:22.437+03:00')),
('D4E77C1', 'buttonClicked',    from_iso8601_timestamp('2021-08-17T14:28:23.572+03:00')),
('D4E77C1', 'measurementCancelled', from_iso8601_timestamp('2021-08-17T14:28:23.573+03:00')),
      
('D4E77C',  'feedbackProvided',  from_iso8601_timestamp('2021-08-18T09:13:00.768+03:00')),
('D4E77C',  'feedbackProvided', from_iso8601_timestamp('2021-08-18T12:06:03.301+03:00')),
('D4E77C',  'feedbackProvided', from_iso8601_timestamp('2021-08-18T14:28:15.083+03:00')),
('D4E77C',  'feedbackProvided', from_iso8601_timestamp('2021-08-18T14:28:17.12+03:00')),
('D4E77C',  'buttonClicked',    from_iso8601_timestamp('2021-08-18T14:28:18.383+03:00')),
('D4E77C',  'measurementStarted',   from_iso8601_timestamp('2021-08-18T14:28:22.437+03:00')),
('D4E77C',  'buttonClicked',    from_iso8601_timestamp('2021-08-18T14:28:23.572+03:00')),
('D4E77C',  'measurementCancelled', from_iso8601_timestamp('2021-08-18T14:28:23.573+03:00'))
    ) AS t (session,    type,   recordedAt)
)
```

```sql
select session, max(recordedAt) - min(recordedAt)
from (
         select *, max(recordedAt) over (partition by session, grp) as m_started_date
         from (
                  select *,
                         sum(case when prev_type = 'measurementStarted' then 1 else 0 end)
                             over (partition by session order by recordedAt) as grp
                  from (
                           select session,
                                  type,
                                  recordedAt,
                                  lag(type) over (partition by session order by recordedAt) as prev_type
                           from dataset
                           where type in ('measurementStarted', 'feedbackProvided')
                       )
              )
     )
where m_started_date - recordedAt < interval '3' minute
group by session, grp
```

Output:

| session | _col1 |
| --- | --- |
| D4E77C1 | 0 00:00:07.354 |
| D4E77C | 0 00:00:07.354 |
| D4E77C | 0 00:00:07.354 |